# How to create an arxml file in java using artop sdk4.12

Tags: java, sdk, autosar

I want to create an ecu extract. For that im using artop sdk. I need to know how to create an arxml file and how to add ARPackage in it using TransactionaleditingDomain?

Comment: You might want to look into the standalone example delivered with the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a simple example at https://github.com/itemis/webinar-artop
Note that you do not need a TransactionalEditingDomain when you just want to create something like a command line tool and not an interactive editing tool.